# Run block using Shift-Enter on the first line on Jupyter Lab text editor

Tags: python, text-editor, jupyter-lab

Is there a way to run a block in in Jupyter Lab's text editor using something like Shift+Enter only the first line (instead of selecting the whole block)?

For example, if I have a a for loop, I need to select the whole for loop to execute it. I know that in other text editors (R, or Juno in Atom) you can just press the run line command in the first line of the for loop and it automatically recognizes it and executes the whole block, whereas in the text editor in Jupyter Lab it only runs the first line (which of course ends in error).

Comment: Seems like you have a cell for each line. Maybe you can add the whole for loop as a cell in itself? Then execute that cell.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. You mean to copy that into a cell in notebook? I would like to do that straight from the text editor.

Comment: Are you referring to the console or to the notebook on Jupyter lab? I can execute a whole block for loop in a single cell on both with Shift + Enter. Do you mind updating with the error and an image?